# How can I select linked objects from multiple parent objects in Laravel Eloquent

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I would like to do something like this.

```js
Location::where('city', '=', 'Chicago')->chef();
```

With these relationships:

```js
class Location extends Eloquent {
    protected $table = 'locations';

    public function chef() {
        return $this->belongsTo('Chef');
    }
}

class Chef extends Eloquent {
    protected $table = 'chefs';

    public function location() {
        return $this->hasMany('Location');
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your question exactly? Also - it is Location::where not Locations::where

Comment: My bad.  Location.  I don't understand the confusion.  I thought I was as clear as I could be. I would like to get all the Chefs for a found set of Locations using a single statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
class Location extends Eloquent {
    protected $table = 'locations';

    public function chefs() {
        return $this->belongsTo('Chef');
    }

    public function getAllChefsByCity($city)
    {
         $this->with('chefs')->where('city', $city)->get();
    }
}
```

Then in your code:

```
$array = $location->getAllChefsByCity('Chicago');
```